# pageY update onScroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, mousemove, onscroll

I'm trying to 'refresh' the pageY value at 'onscroll' event.
I actually made it work by calculating where the mouse would be if the user scrolled (+-)X pixels. I'm sure there is sexier way of doing it.

[Here is a DEMO](http://jsbin.com/kegodunuma/edit?html,js,output)

Thanks in advance

P.s.

```
$(document).bind('mousemove scroll', function(e){ //do stuff});
```

that didn't work

Answer (score 1):

I didn't actually test it, but something like this could work:

```
<script>
...
...
defaultHeight = 2000;

    $(window).scroll(function(){
        maskbehind.style.height = defaultHeight + window.pageYOffset;
    }
...
...
</script>
```

Note that the actual height of the client is a read-only value (window.innerHeight).

I hope I didn't misunderstand your intentions!

Comment: this is what the code looks like now... my TOStoMouse = your defaultHeight//TopOfStageToMouse

Comment: I don't know any another way to do this..PS: Use better named variables :)

Comment: The variables are  not the same.. defaultHeight does not change, it's always 2000. (Your css-defined height for 'mask-behind'). TOStoMouse is the distance from the top of the screen to the mouse pointer.. Big difference :)